# ENV variables in Rails 7.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-7

This might be silly but I need help in finding where my ENV file is. I am unable to view my ENV file.

When I started my rails app, some of the values were `ENV["var_name"]`, eg: `ENV[" DATABASE_PASSWORD"]` so I assumed those environment variables must be stored somewhere. but it is nowhere to be found.

When it comes to the Figaro gem we store it in `config/application.yml`. Another way is storing them in other YML files and loading them in the "config" folder. but there is no code added for it. since it is newly created, no code was added to the Rails app.

I also checked my Gemfile and Gemlock files. there was no "Dotenv" or "Figaro" present. Does Rails provide this ENV feature thing in-built?

I might be missing something or might not be aware of something. Enlighten me on how to view this file and update the ENV variables. Thanks, folks.

p.s: I use Windows machine.

Answer (score 5):

Rails has no `.env` support built-in, but the `dotenv` gem provides easy support for it, and the [installation process is simple](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).

Note you don't necessarily need `.env`, it's just a very convenient way of doing that, you can set them as "real" environment variables through your shell.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused about where the ENV["DATABASE_PASSWORD"] resides. As said there is no gem nor any .env files in the application that maintains this value. Is it expected to directly add the value via shell?

Comment: It's an environment variable, so there's many ways to introduce it: `.bashrc` or equivalent, `export` in your shell, or `X=y ...` prefixes when running commands. Since these are so ubiquitous there's a multitude of ways to add them, but `.env` is the most self-contained and is a convention that extends well beyond just Rails. Docker has direct support, and Node, Python and others via "dotenv" extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Check config/credentials.yml.enc

If you don't have the credentials.yml.enc file in your app already you can run : `EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit` to either open or generate the file.

See these for more info on how to add/edit credentials and why this is the new preferred practice and Rails 6/7 default:

https://web-crunch.com/posts/the-complete-guide-to-ruby-on-rails-encrypted-credentials

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/switching-from-env-files-to-rails-credentials